# Does a possible error from getStaticProps affect SEO?

Tags: next.js

In the following code, I'll give an example of a Blog Article. The article content will only be rendered if there are no errors coming from getStaticProps. Let's say that for some reason, someday an error comes from getStaticProps, since this error will prevent the content rendering, how much will affect SEO?

```
export const BlogHome: NextPage<PropsFromGetStaticProps> = ({ error, article }) => {
  return (
    <_div>
      {!error ? (
        <>
          <Head>
            <title>{article.title}</title>
          </Head>
          <main>
            <h1>{article.title}</h1>
            <p>{article.description}</p>
          </main>
        </>
      ) : null}
    </_div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What will get rendered in case of such an error?

Comment: I would probably redirect the user to a 404 page, since the article data is invalid. Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: Yes, that's the right thing to do. But keep in mind that `getStaticProps` generates static pages, unless you're using ISR the pages generated at build time will not change.